# Not able to connect to Snowflake from fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, connection, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-fargate

I am trying to connect to snowflake from fargate. I have tried different configs from source code but all of my attempts are failed. I am able to connect to snowflake from my local but not from fargate instances.

```
    engine = create_engine(
        'snowflake://{user}:{password}@{account}/'.format(
            user="*",
            password="*",
            account="*.us-east-1",
            insecure_mode=True,
            ocsp_fail_open=False,
            proxy_host="https://proxy.com",
            proxy_port=80
        )
```

Also tried building docker file with proxy configs 
`docker build -t file_conversion_worker . --build-arg http_proxy=https:proxy.com:port --build-arg http_proxy=https://proxy.com:port`

What I am I missing here?

Comment: Can you share the error you are getting?

Comment: The error would help and also what you have tried so far.  Is everything setup in the same region? Is the issue specific to Fargate?

Comment: This is resolved, needed docker configs ```ENV HTTPS_PROXY="http://someproxy.com:"
ENV HTTP_PROXY="http://someproxy.com:80"
ENV NO_PROXY=".amazonaws.com"```

The error was ```This connection is in OCSP Fail Open Mode. TLS Certificates would be checked for validity and revocation status. Any other Certificate Revocation related exceptions or OCSP Responder failures would be disregarded in favor of connectivity.``` I tried setting up the docker container with proxy multiple times on the other day; all the deployments had the same error message. I think it was bad docker builds earlier.